# NHibernate: SQL query results mapping

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I have a problem with a SQL query results in NHibernate 3.1.0.4000 (I'm using MS SQL Server 2005 database). I have two tables: `Adverts` and `Investments`, which are mapped to entities: `Advert` and `Investment`. `Adverts` are connected with `Investments` via `InvestmentId` column (and a foreign key).

To save results of my query I created a following inner class:

```
    class InvestmentWithAdvertsCount
    {
        public Investment inv { get; set; }

        public int cnt { get; set; }
    }
```

and the query is as follows:

```
var investementsWithAdvertCounts = _session.CreateSQLQuery(
                            "select {inv.*}, (select count(1) from Adverts where InvestmentId = inv.Id) cnt from Investments inv")
                            .AddScalar("cnt", NHibernateUtil.Int32)
                            .AddEntity("inv", typeof(Investment))
                            .SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(InvestmentWithAdvertsCount)))
                            .List<InvestmentWithAdvertsCount>();
```

When I run this query I receive a collection of `InvestmentWithAdvertsCount` instances that have a correctly filled `cnt` property, but the `inv` property is set to `null`. I spent some time digging into the NHibernate source and it seems that the *inv* alias is somehow lost from the query and NHibernate does not even try to fill the `inv` property. If I remove the `.SetResultTransformer` part I receive a list of arrays (of type `object[2]`) with first element set to `Investment` entity and second element set to its corresponding adverts count. Could you please tell me how to change this query to make the `InvestmentWithAdvertsCount` filled correctly? Or maybe there is a way to rewrite this query to QueryOver, Criteria or HQL (keeping the generated SQL code efficient)?

I would be really greatful for any help on this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a clean way to do it, processing the results with very simple LINQ to objects:

```
session.CreateSQLQuery(
    "select {inv.*}, (select count(1) ... inv")
    .AddScalar("cnt", NHibernateUtil.Int32)
    .AddEntity("inv", typeof(Investment))
    .List<object[]>()
    .Select(x => new InvestmentWithAdvertsCount {inv = x[0], cnt = x[1]})
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Tahnks Diego. This is actually what I finally did:) I was only interested whether there is anyone who can explain why the Transformers.AliasToBean is not working. However I will plus you up and in case no other answer is provided I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: IIRC, AliasToBean works with scalar properties, not entity aliases. IOW, it doesn't even *see* that "inv" you defined, because that results in several result columns, none of which is named "inv".